# Table variable and exec

Tags: t-sql, exec, local-variables

How can I use a table variable while executing a command string?

```
DECLARE @FileIDs TABLE 
(
   File_ID int
)
insert into @FileIDs select ID from Files where Name like '%bla%';

DECLARE @testquery as varchar(max);
set @testquery = 'select * from @FileIDs';
exec(@testquery);
```

returns the following error

Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the table variable "@FileIDs".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The table `@FileIDs` is not in the scope of `exec(@testquery)`.

That's why you have that problem.

---

To solve this problem you may use a `temporary table`:

```
CREATE table #FileIDs
(
   File_ID int
)
insert into #FileIDs select ID from Files where Name like '%bla%'; 

DECLARE @testquery as varchar(max);
set @testquery = 'select * from #FileIDs';
exec(@testquery);

drop table #FileIDs
```

**or** put the table in the scope:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000)

SET @sql='DECLARE @FileIDs TABLE (   File_ID int);'
SET @sql=@sql+'insert into @FileIDs select ID from Files where Name like ''%bla%'';'
set @sql=@sql+ 'select * from @FileIDs;'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: For those who vote up: this is a copy&paste of [this original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11360793/1426685)

Answer (score 4):

Indeed table is out of the scope, try this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000)

SET @sql='DECLARE @FileIDs TABLE (   File_ID int);'
SET @sql=@sql+'insert into @FileIDs select ID from Files where Name like ''%bla%'';'
set @sql=@sql+ 'select * from @FileIDs;'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 CREATE table #FileIDs
(
   File_ID int
)
insert into #FileIDs select ID from Files where Name like '%bla%'; 

DECLARE @testquery as varchar(max);
set @testquery = 'select * from #FileIDs';
exec(@testquery);

drop table #FileIDs
```

Comment: In the insert, you have `@` and you should have `#`.